# A statistical test for comparison between two R square values?

Tags: regression, amos

We are looking for a method to compare two R square values obtained from two identical models (for instance, time 1 and time 2, within subject design).
We preformed two path analysis using AMOS and got several R squares. These are two identical models, obtained from data in time 1, and the second one (within subjects) obtained from time 2. We want to compare these R square values and test for significance.
Any ideas what will work here?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to decide on an approach to take, and haven't gotten to the programming part yet. Is that right?

Comment: We preformed two  path analysis using AMOS and got several R squares. These are two identical models, obtained from data in time 1, and the second one (within subjects) obtained from time 2. We want to compare these R square values and test for significance.